# User interface for multi-dimensional data presented as lists

Tags: lists, multi-column, right-click

I have an application that lists all the modules loaded in a performance test in a *baseline* and a *current* testrun. Each run in turn has many *iterations*. A user can view the difference of what was loaded in the baseline versus current across all iterations by selecting **All** in the dropdown list. 
[image: Current UI]

However, I want to add the ability to go to another tool for the following combination of parameters (module, runtype(baseline or current) and iteration (0,1,2,..)) etc.
For example: I will open up a call stack for **Module0.dll** in **baseline** testrun for **iteration 1**.

However, iterations don't show up in this UI as the values in baseline and current columns are *aggregates* across all iterations.

My idea was to make the cell values in baseline and current as hyperlinks where a user can right-click -> see a menu of iterations and click on a particular iteration to go to the new tool. I am not sure that it is the best user experience/UI though.

Any suggestion on improving this workflow will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the goal of the observing separate iterations? It's a long and boring task. Aggregation allows to cope with a huge amount of data, while observation of each iteration leads to increasing workload. Probably, you need some tool for finding iterations which have bad performance?

Comment: I show aggregates above and that is sufficient for the first level of analysis into a regression. However, to go one level further, you want to see call stacks. Call stacks are different for different iterations. I want the user to be able to compare one call stack to the other. And I want them to get to the callStackViewer tool from the UI shown above.

Answer (score 1):

This interface is clearly not for your average user. Though I can quickly rattle off a solution that would be best for *everyone*, what you really need is a solution that is best for *your users*. This is the difference between Human-Centered design and User-Centered design.

I won't provide you with a wireframe or mockup, because I'd have to make a lot of assumptions about your users to do that. I don't know them, but you do! Because of this **I don't think anyone here can provide you with the right answer**, unless it's on accident.

Instead, here are some things to ponder that can help you along the way:

- What kind of software do your users interface with commonly?
- How do your users visualize this problem?
- Why do your users need this feature?
- Where in their workflow does this exists?
- How would you present this information on a printed page or some other non-digital format?
- What is the most-efficient/simple solution you can think of visually and how does it different from the most-efficient/simple solution pragmatically?